# How to compile Quake 2 source?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++

I've [downloaded](https://archive.org/details/Quake_2_source_code) the full Quake2 source code but having a problem compiling the `ref_soft` project (`ref_soft.dll`) inside the solution. I'm getting `cannot open input file '.\..\debug\\.obj` All other projects in the solution compiles just OK with the same settings. Any idea what to change to compile the `ref_soft`?

I'm using MSVC 2019 on Win 10.

Comment: You should probably use one of the open source forks, since they have done all the work of porting it to a modern environment already.

Comment: @HansPassant. Thx for help:-) Can You be so nice and show me Your's working .vcxproj file?

Comment: @HansPassant Hello. Can You be so nice and answer my last entry?

Answer (score -2):

There is a list of projects that have already accomplished that task here: https://quake.fandom.com/wiki/List_of_Quake_II_Source_ports

I would consider looking into how they made it work (seems like a large effort).